# Trigger to Update Contact fields by last modified task fields

Tags: trigger, query, map

I want to update my contacts 3 custom fields with task fields when ever new task created,Updated,deleted.If the task is deleted then the last inserted should replace the field values with its values and if it is transferred to another contact then the last inserted should replace the value on the contact. 
Here is Code:

```
Trigger NewWayUpdateContact on task(after insert,after update,after delete,after undelete){
    set<string> whoIds=new set<string>();
    if(trigger.IsInsert||trigger.IsUndelete||trigger.IsUpdate){
        for(task t:trigger.new){
            whoIds.add(t.WhoId);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.Isdelete){
        for(task t:trigger.old){
            whoIds.add(t.WhoId);
        }
    }
     List<Contact> ConToUpdLst = new List<Contact>();
     List<task> tasklist= [SELECT Id,subject,priority,ActivityDate,whoId FROM task WHERE Id =: whoIds];
     Map<id,list<task>> taskMap = new Map<id,list<task>>();

        for(Task t :tasklist){  
            if(!taskMap.cotainskey(t.whoId)){     
                taskMap.put(t.whoId, new list<task>());       
            }     
            taskMap.get(t.whoId).add(t);
        }

         for(Id conId:taskMap.keyset()){
              Id ConToUpdId;
              String sub;
              DateTime Due_Date;
              String pri;
              Datetime max = Datetime.newinstance(2004, 5, 20);
              for(Task ts:taskMap.get(conId)){    
                  if( ts.LastModifiedDate > max ){
                        max = ts.LastModifiedDate;
                        ConToUpdId = conId;
                        sub = ts.Subject;
                        Due_Date = ts.ActivityDate;
                        pri = ts.Priority;
                  }
                       Contact con = new Contact( Id=ConToUpdId );
                       con.Subject__c = sub;
                       con.Priority__c = pri;
                       con.Due_Date__c = Due_Date;
                       ConToUpdLst.add( con );

              }
         }
         if( ConToUpdLst.size() > 0 ){
            update ConToUpdLst;
         }
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

I did a small poc for you to practice myself.

Here I have a trigger on task and update task last modified date on contact.

Trigger:

```
Trigger TaskTrigger on Task(after insert, after update, after delete) {

    if(Trigger.isinsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        TaskHelper.updateTask(Trigger.new);
    }
    else if(Trigger.isDelete){
        TaskHelper.updateTask(Trigger.old);
    }
}
```

And Helper class:

```
public class TaskHelper {
    public static void updateTask(List<Task> taskList) {
        Map<Id,Datetime > idLastModifiedDateMap = new Map<Id,Datetime >();
        List<id> contactIdList = new List<Id>();
        for(Task temp : taskList) {
            if(String.valueOf(temp.WhoId).subString(0,3) == '003') {
                contactIdList.add(temp.WhoId);
            }
        }

        for(Task temp : [Select id,LastModifiedDate,WhoId From Task Where whoId in :contactIdList Order by LastModifiedDate ASC]) {
            idLastModifiedDateMap.put(temp.WhoId,temp.LastMOdifiedDate);                
        }

        List<Contact> contactList = [Select id,Description from contact where id in :idLastModifiedDateMap.keySet()];
        for(Contact temp : contactList) {
            temp.Description= String.valueOf(idLastModifiedDateMap.get(temp.id));
        }
        update contactList;        
    }       
}
```